# How can I convert an enery sorted .traj (trajectory) file into an ID sorted file using?

Tags: python, genetic-algorithm

This is a part of a thesis problem in which it is required to use the Atomic Simulation Environment (ASE) library in python to ID-sort the already energy-sorted atoms and then through a for loop, find out the minimum energy as well as the number of iterations it takes to find out the atom with the least energy (global minimum)

I have used the code of `sort_traj _by_id` to ID-sort the `all_candidates.traj` file but could not get what is required.

following is the main file (test.py)

```
from ase import *
from ase.io import read,write
from ase.visualize import view
all_traj = read('all_candidates.traj@:')
e_min = 1000
counter0 = 0
for i in all_traj:
    e = i.get_potential_energy()
    if e < e_min:
      e_min = e
      counter0 += 1
print ('least energy is ' + str(e_min))
print('number of steps to reach global minimum is ' + str(counter0))
```

following is the file which is to be used to convert energy sorted atoms to ID sorted atoms (sort_traj _by_id)

```
from ase.io import write,read
from optparse import OptionParser
from ase import *
import sys
fname  = sys.argv[1]
label = fname[:-5]
t = read(fname+'@:')   
t.sort(key=lambda x: x.info['confid'])
write(label+'_idsorted.traj', t)
```

Actual result:

```
nadir@nadir-Inspiron-3521:~/Desktop/ase_folder$ python test.py
```

least energy is 7.30578716461
number of steps to reach global minimum is 1

In the above output, the 'number of steps required to reach global minimum is 1' because the atoms are ordered by their energies and the first atom has the lowest energy so the global minimum is reached with first iteration. I have to arrange the atoms not by energies but by their ID so that the global minimum can be reached by any number of iterations and not just one every time.